# Can I access method within the same export?

Tags: javascript

I have a module that I require in another location, here is an example (call this `lib.js`):

```
module.exports = {
    a:{
        someFunc: function()
        {

        }
    },
    b:{
        someOtherFunc: function()
        {

        }
    }

}
```

My other file would be like so:

```
const lib = require('./lib.js');
lib.a.someFunc();
```

But what if i want to access `a.someFunc()` from `b.someOtherFunc()`?

I have tried using `this.a.someFunc()` but that doesn't work, probably because it's not an instantiated object as such. I have also tried `exports.a.someFunc()` but that also doesn't work.

So neither of these work:

```
module.exports = {
        a:{
            someFunc: function()
            {
    
            }
        },
        b:{
            someOtherFunc: function()
            {
                this.a.someFunc();
                exports.a.someFunc();
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Why not move the definitions of `a` and `b` out, so that `module.exports = { a, b }` and `a.someFunc()` works?

Comment: What do you mean try to access `a.someFunc` from `b.someOtherFunc` ? They are explicitly encapsulated objects. If you want to reference then just define them in the global scope and then do `module.exports = { a , b }`

Comment: Ok cool! Both said the same thing, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You have to define them separatly like this

```js
const a = {
  someFunc: function() {

  }
}
const b  = {
  someOtherFunc: function() {
    a.someFunc();
  }
}

module.exports = {a, b}
```